# How to make arranged offset-views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

This is my code for making offset text view for my icons. The red line is center line of my app which cannot be moved to left or right. Therefore, I am adding the text view overlay to my views to not mess up the center line and also make the code reusable.

I want all my texts to start from the black line. I made a parameter to set the needed offset, but the text itself has a different length as well, so that messes up my plan.

How can I solve this issue?

```
    VStack {
                
                Image(systemName: "dock.arrow.up.rectangle")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
                    .textView(text: "FullSizeView", offset: 50.0)

                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30.0, height: 30.0)
                    .textView(text: "Quit", offset: 50.0)
                
    }
```

```
    extension View {
    
    func textView(text: String, offset: CGFloat) -> some View {
        
        self
            .overlay(content: {
                
                Text(text)
                    .fixedSize()
                    .bold()
                    .offset(x: offset)

            })
    }
    
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `Label`?

Comment: No, the text would not be there for all time, they would show up with animation from red line to black. The label can do this animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it:

**1. Using `alignmentGuide`**

Provided your containing view uses `Horizontal.center` alignment, you can apply an `.alignmentGuide` inside your extension:

```swift
extension View {
    func textView(text: String, offset: CGFloat) -> some View {
        self.overlay(
            Text(text)
                .bold()
                .fixedSize()
                .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { d in
                    d[.leading] - offset
                }
        )
    }
}
```

**2. Using hidden text of the same width**

You can balance the text using the same text but hidden:

```swift
extension View {
    func textView(text: String, offset: CGFloat) -> some View {
        self.overlay(
            HStack(spacing: 2 * offset) {
                Text(text).hidden()
                Text(text)
            }
            .bold()
            .fixedSize()
        )
    }
}
```

This one could also be implemented using a `ZStack` instead of an overlay, which would mean it would contribute to layout calculations and the text could wrap, if it needed to:

```swift
extension View {
    func textView(text: String, offset: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            self
            HStack(spacing: 2 * offset) {
                Text(text).hidden()
                Text(text)
            }
            .bold()
        }
    }
}
```

The results are the same:

[image: OffsetText]

The screenshot uses an offset of 50, as in your original example.